# I do not want collapsing toolbar to scroll at all inside coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a code here which contains of a coordinator layout. Inside that coordinator layout, there is an appbar layout and a nested scrollview beneath it.I want the appbar layout(map) to be still even when nestedscroll view scrolls.I have images to explain my thoughts. [Initial stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExmVH.png), [stage two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PACI7.png). Notice that the map remains still while only nested scroll view scrolls and finally, nested scroll view overlaps entire map fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/close_button"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/close_black"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shipping_to_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SHIPPING TO"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shipping_to"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="926 Rosenbaum Mill"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_below="@id/shipping_to_title"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                tools:context=".MapFragment"
                android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/outermost_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        >
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/getDirections"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_activity_get_directions_fragment_layout"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            />
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/received"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_activity_received_fragment_layout"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            />
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/enrouteToDestination"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_activity_button_fragment_layout"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            />
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/trackOrder"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_track_order_button_fragment_layout"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            />
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/trackOrderBelow"
                            android:layout_width="300dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/trackOrder"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:background="#FBFBFB"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tracking_code_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/tracking_code"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tracking_code"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/tracking_code_numbers"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tracking_code_title"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/double_boxes"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </fragment>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/abc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/MyAppbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            tools:context=".MapFragment">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_wrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/activity_background">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relative_layout_inner"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/white"
                            android:focusedByDefault="true">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/order_icon"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                android:src="@drawable/orders" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/order_date_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/order_icon"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/order_date2"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/order_date"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/order_date_title"
                                android:gravity="center|end"
                                android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                                android:text="@string/date5"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/placeBy_icon"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/order_icon"
                                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                android:src="@drawable/person" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/placed_by_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/order_date_title"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/placeBy_icon"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/placed_by"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/placed_by"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_below="@id/order_date_title"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/placed_by_title"
                                android:gravity="center|end"
                                android:paddingLeft="100dp"
                                android:text="@string/user_name"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/delivery_icon"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/placeBy_icon"
                                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                android:src="@drawable/delivery" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/delivery_method_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/placed_by_title"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/delivery_icon"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/delivery_method"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/delivery_method"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_below="@id/placed_by_title"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/delivery_method_title"
                                android:gravity="center|end"
                                android:text="@string/shipping"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/add_to_calander_button_shipment"
                                android:layout_width="340dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_icon"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/add_to_calander">

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/addToCalIcon"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                        android:src="@drawable/orders" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/addToCalText"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/addToCalIcon"
                                        android:text="@string/add_to_calander"
                                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/threeItems"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout_inner"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:background="@color/activity_background" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/threeItemstext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout_inner"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:text="@string/number_of_items"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                            android:id="@+id/nestedRecyclerView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_below="@id/threeItems">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/simpleRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@android:color/white"
                                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                                app:layout_behavior="@string/app_bar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/delivery_details"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_delivery_details_fragment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/nestedRecyclerView"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/order"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_order_total_fragment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/delivery_details"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/need_help"
                            layout="@layout/track_shipment_need_help_fragment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/order"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, if you don't wanna collapsing toolbar to collapse, use for example RelativeLayout instead of collapsing toolbar.

Comment: I basically want the my map, should remain still, my nested scrollview should overlap the map when nested scrollview scrolls. I am new to android. Collapsing toolbar was the only way I could achive what I wanted. If there are any other tools by which I could do this, please let me know.

Comment: So map should remain on the screen or should it be overlapped by scrollView? you write both in your comment ....

Comment: map should remain on screen(still) and when scrollview is scrolled, it should scroll over map.

Comment: you can do a hack for that, place map fragment on FrameLayout and all the Coordination layout below it with empty transparent view with the same height as map fragment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 
`app:behavior_overlapTop="0dp"` in your **nested scroll view** and also add some elevation to the nested scroll view.